# What is the interpretation of the plot boxes of Logistic Model Tree (LMT) outcome in the RWeka package in r?

Tags: r, plot, rweka

Im working on a user classification with 5 known groups (observations approximatly equally divided over groups). I have information about these users (like age, living area ...) and try to find the characteristics that identify the users in each group.

For this purpose I use the Rweka package in R (collection of machine learning algorithms: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RWeka/RWeka.pdf). To find the characteristics that distinguish between my groups I use Logistic Model Trees (LMT). There is just little information about this function:

1. I will try to sketch an example of a plotted tree.
   The splits are straight forward for interpretation, but in each terminal node there is a box filled with:

LM_24:  48/96

(20742)

What does this mean? How can I see in which of the five groups the node ends?

2. With what function can I retrieve the coefficients used in the model? Such that the influence of the variables can be studied.

(I did look into other methods for building trees on these data, but both the regression and classification tree packages (like rpart, party) only find one terminal note in my data, whilest the LMT function finds 6 split nodes)

I hope you can provide me the answer/some help with this function. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think your question would suit better to http://stats.stackexchange.com/, as it does not necessarily involve R